# Money change/minimum coin algorithm

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

How can I speed up this code?

```py
coin=[50000, 20000, 10000, 5000, 2000, 1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1]
def matrix(coins, kerdes): # it create a metrix
    tabla = [[0 for m in range(kerdes + 1)] for m in range(len(coins) + 1)]

    for i in range(kerdes + 1):
        tabla[0][i] = i
    return tabla

def change_making(coin, change):
    table = matrix(coin, change)
    for c in range(1, len(coin) + 1):
        for r in range(1, change + 1):

            if coin[c - 1] == r:
                table[c][r] = 1

            elif coin[c - 1]> r:
                table[c][r] = table[c-1][r]

            else:
                table[c][r] = min(table[c - 1][r], 1 + table[c][r - coin[c - 1]])

    return table[-1][-1] #return the minimum coin what we need to make the change

newcoin=int(input()) # ask the new coin
coin.append(newcoin) #add to the coin list
coin.sort(reverse=True) #sort the list to get the biggest coin to first

changemakings=[int(x) for x in input().split()] # order the 'orders' to list for easier work with it
for changes in changemakings:

    print(change_making(coin, changes))
```

This is my code it calculate the minimum coin, with possible to give new coin which will result a non canonical change system.

Comment: post a testable `changemakings` list values

Comment: from 1 to 10^7 like [1,18,35,4587425,9400]

Comment: Can you clarify what does "minimum change" (as resulting digit) conceptually mean? Please provide a more extended description

Comment: Yes i miss wrote it. I meant coin.

Answer (score 1):

I ran a few examples through the code and I have made the following assumptions:

- the code calculates the minimum amount of coins needed to produce the user's input
- the user can enter in a custom coin and it will use that as part of its calculations

Instead of using a matrix, I just found the highest coin which can be used to make change, then subtracted it from the total user inputted amount, and repeated it until there was no change left.

```
coins = [50000, 20000, 10000, 5000, 2000, 1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1]

coinToAdd = int(input("Enter in coin to add to coins:"))
userMoney = int(input("Enter in coin to calculate change:"))
coins.append(coinToAdd)
coins.sort(reverse=True)
totalCoins = 0
while [j for j in coins if userMoney >= j]:
  userMoney = userMoney - [j for j in coins if userMoney >= j][0]
  totalCoins = totalCoins + 1

print(totalCoins)
```